# How do I check user by ID or Name?

Tags: telethon

I want to check if the message what I got comes form the particular user and I want to check him by his Name or ID, because for some users I don't know the Id yet. Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Can you give a bit more of context?
Do you get the message from a database, how does the schema looks like?

Maybe some code would be helpful as well

The biggest question would be from my side:
How can a user have created or referenced by a message when he isn't created?

Possible solution would be:
1. Always attach an ID to an user as soon as he is created
2. as soon as you get a message without an user ID, create a user with that ID

Keep in mind:
I don't know how you system looks like, what data you need for creating a user etc.

Comment: Sorry! I was asking about python library "telethon".

Comment: you can simply create an issue on the github repository
else I would suggest, that you put that library name in the question so people who know how to use it can find your question and help you :)

unfortunately I never used this library before, sorry